# How to add new line in fulfillmentText in Dialogflow for web?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow v2 API and accessing my agent through their Web Demo link. I have a webhook server using Flask and I am constructing my response and sending it back to user through fulfillmentText key.I want to show my reply in a new line but I am unable to generate one.

I have tried multiple options like: '\n' , '\n  \n', &nbsp, <\br>, etc. but nothing seems to work for web based access. Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: maybe u need to send multiply responses from backend if u want get it easier

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `fulfillment_messages` field instead. `fulfillment_text` is a legacy field, so `fulfillment_messages` should be instead.

`fulfillment_messages` is a collection, so messages will be displayed line-by-line in the order you have added them.

Documentation here: [QueryResult documentation](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html?highlight=queryresult#dialogflow_v2.types.QueryResult)